# Eclipse Android ADT22 - Librairies/dependencies problems - Already tried everything

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

As many people have notices, since the latest release of the ADT PLugin for Eclipse, the librairies handling has changed.

```
05-28 01:59:30.388: E/AndroidRuntime(22867): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 01:59:30.388: E/AndroidRuntime(22867): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker
05-28 01:59:30.388: E/AndroidRuntime(22867):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(GoogleAccountCredential.java:171)
05-28 01:59:30.388: E/AndroidRuntime(22867):    at edu.kaist.wst660.bmaingret.android.RegisterActivity.chooseAccount(RegisterActivity.java:85)
05-28 01:59:30.388: E/AndroidRuntime(22867):    at edu.kaist.wst660.bmaingret.android.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:50)
05-28 01:59:30.388: E/AndroidRuntime(22867):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
05-28 01:59:30.388: E/AndroidRuntime(22867):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329)
05-28 01:59:30.388: E/AndroidRuntime(22867):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-28 01:59:30.388: E/AndroidRuntime(22867):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-28 01:59:30.388: E/AndroidRuntime(22867):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 01:59:30.388: E/AndroidRuntime(22867):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
05-28 01:59:30.388: E/AndroidRuntime(22867):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 01:59:30.388: E/AndroidRuntime(22867):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 01:59:30.388: E/AndroidRuntime(22867):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:986)
05-28 01:59:30.388: E/AndroidRuntime(22867):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:753)
05-28 01:59:30.388: E/AndroidRuntime(22867):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The `google-code-api-client` is in the `libs` folder. It shows up in the `Android private librairies`.

I checked the export option in the project>build path settings.

I build the project from the command-line with `android debug` and it didn't show up any errors.

The new SDK Build Tools is installed.

And yet I still have this error....

Please help me!

## Solution-----------------------------------------

You need to check the above instructions for every project that you use.

In my case `google-play`services` librairy project was missing the Export checkbox in the project settings.

Comment: is google-code-api-client a library project?

Comment: Does your project contain any library projects then?

Comment: Yes, see my comment in the acepted answer. It was a problem with the google-play-service librairy. Thanks

Comment: Why in every adt update they need to mess up something.

Comment: I have two projects. I lost roughly 3 hours on overall because of this. I mean how hard is it to at least give some warnings when upgrading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had same problem, until I add:

import com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker;

at my activity.java file.

and one more thin you need to make sure  google play service imported and checked in order and export

it may help you...

Comment: Thank you. I added it. Then I got an import error because it could find the class. It appears that I didn't check the export in the google-play-services project...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem after update plug-in to v22 and with few hours struggling I fired up SDK manager again and found out, that there is new entry which wasn't there before (Android SDK build-tools), I downloaded it and everything started working again.